# user-messaging-platform error on play console

Tags: java, ump

I have an app in production on the Google Play console and it is giving some users errors since I implemented the com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:2.1.0 library.  The “Mobile Ads SDK team” tells me the following:

“To resolve this issue, update dependencies to a version built using a JDK version that matches the JDK version used to build the application. For example, if we build an application using JDK 13, the dependencies should be built using JDK 13”

1.-Where do I find the JDK version in which the "com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:2.1.0" dependency was compiled?

2.- How do I find a version of "com.google.android.:2.1.0" with the jdk compatible with that of my app?
I'm using Android studio 4.0.0.
The error it shows me in the google play console is the following:
Excepción java.lang.VerifyError:
at java.lang.Class.newInstance
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity (AppComponentFactory.java:95)
....

Thanks for help me

I have this configuration in the app project.
[app configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCtB7.png)
[app configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90vIf.png)